# Adding calendar control on side bar of publishing site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-calendar, 2016

If I add SharePoint OOB calendar web part on side bar of home page, will it automatically fit inside whatever space is available or do I need to create a custom web part that will read data from calendar and display?

I mean normally the calendar web part takes whole page so I am not sure if it will adjust automatically in side bar where limited width is available.

Thanks